# Sum of random points on a (complex) sphere

Tags: probability, exponential-function, density-function, trigonometric-series

Suppose we have $N$ spherical surfaces with radius distributed i.i.d. according to the PDF $$f_{d}(r) = \frac{3r^2}{R_{\text{max}}^3 - R_{\text{min}}^3}$$ on $[R_{\text{min}},R_{\text{max}}]$.  On each surface, choose a point $d_i$ uniformly at random.

Choose a particular $d_k$.  I am trying to evaluate the expectation $$\mathbb{E}[\left |\sum_{i=1}^N \exp \left ( 2\pi j(d_{i}-d_{k}) \right ) \right |^2]\tag{1}$$ in the case $R_{min} \leq d_{i} \leq R_{max}$.  There, (1) simplifies to $$ 
\mathbb{E}\left [\left(\sum_{i=1}^N \cos \left (\frac{2\pi(d_i-d_k)}{\lambda} \right )\right)^2 \right ] + 
\mathbb{E}\left [\left(\sum_{i=1}^N \sin \left (\frac{2\pi(d_i-d_k)}{\lambda} \right )\right)^2 \right]^2\tag{2}
$$  Note that each expectation is very symmetric: it is the square of a sum over all $N$ points chosen from the distribution, a set from which $d_k$ was chosen.  Can we apply facts about equidistant points on a circle to finish?

Comment: Please don't close it give it a try

Comment: We can't follow what you're asking.  I just made a substantial edit based on my guesses about what you meant.  Please check that what I wrote is what you intend.

Comment: In particular: (1) I don't think $f_d$ is the uniform distribution _on the sphere_.  Did you mean it to be?  (2) Should $d_k$ be chosen randomly from the $\{d_j\}_{j=1}^N$, or is it fixed?  (3) What is your end goal?  Do you want a formula in terms of the $\{d_j\}_j$ or are you looking for an [expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value)?  How simple should it be?

Comment: What is $R_{min}$? What is $R_{max}$?

Comment: Yess  @JacobManaker $f_d$ is not uniform it the probability density function of radius of spherical surface. $d_k$ is fixed for a particular equation. I am trying to get this summation thing solved somehow in equation (2)

Comment: @YaniorWeg $R_{min}$ and $R_{max}$ is the minimum and maximum value the radius of sphere can take at any instant

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that $d_i$ are i.i.d. random variables on $[R_{min}; R_{max}]$?

Comment: @YaniorWeg Yess

Comment: Also, when you say you want to "evaluate" the sum, do you want to find its expectation or its PDF?

Comment: @YaniorWeg Exceptation of this expression in equation 2

Comment: I've added the facts about iid-ness and looking for an expectation to the question.

Comment: Can you solve this @YaniorWeg

Comment: @parveen: Let me check I understand correctly: (1) the radii of the spheres are chosen randomly and iid according to f (2) for each spherical surface, the corresponding d_k is chosen uniformly at random.  Is this right?

Comment: @JacobManaker yes now you are right

Comment: @JacobManaker can you solve it

Answer (score 1):

I don't think splitting up into sines and cosines is usable this early.  Instead, note that the magnitude of an absolute value is given by multiplying by the complex conjugate: $$|z|^2=zz^*$$  Now expand the square: \begin{align*}
\left|\sum_i{\exp{\!\left(\frac{2\pi j}{\lambda}(d_i-d_k)\right)}}\right|^2&=\sum_i{\exp{\!\left(\frac{2\pi j}{\lambda}(d_i-d_k)+\frac{2\pi j}{\lambda}(d_k-d_i)\right)}}+\\
&\phantom{{}={}}\quad\quad\sum_{i\neq l}{\exp{\!\left(\frac{2\pi j}{\lambda}(d_i-d_k)+\frac{2\pi j}{\lambda}(d_k-d_l)\right)}} \\
&=\sum_i{1}+\sum_{i\neq l}{\exp{\!\left(\frac{2\pi j}{\lambda}(d_i-d_l)\right)}}
\end{align*}  Interestingly, $d_k$ has vanished: the result is independent of which $d_i$ you choose.

At this point, one can refactorize, but then independent random variables get all intermixed.  So we shan't.

By linearity of expectation, it suffices to find the expectation of each summand.  The first sum is just $N$; the second has identically-distributed terms.  So we seek \begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left[\left|\sum_i{\exp{\!\left(\frac{2\pi j}{\lambda}(d_i-d_k)\right)}}\right|^2\right]&=N+2(N-1)\mathbb{E}\left[\exp{\!\left(\frac{2\pi j}{\lambda}(d_1-d_2)\right)}\right] \\
&=N+2(N-1)\mathbb{E}\left[e^{\frac{2\pi jd_1}{\lambda}}\right]\mathbb{E}\left[e^{-\frac{2\pi jd_2}{\lambda}}\right]
\end{align*} by independence.

To evaluate these expectations, we use the [law of the unconscious statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) (note that the radius of $d_1$ and its angle are independent): $$\mathbb{E}\left[e^{\frac{2\pi jd_1}{\lambda}}\right]=\int_{R_{\text{min}}}^{R_{\text{max}}}{\int_0^{2\pi}{\exp{\!\left(\frac{2\pi j}{\lambda}\cdot re^{\theta j}\right)}\left(\frac{d\theta}{2\pi}\right)}\left(f_d(r)\,dr\right)}$$

I will interpret the inner integral as a [contour integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_integration).  Let $C$ denote the counterclockwise circular contour of radius $\frac{2\pi r}{\lambda}$ starting at $1$.  Then
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{2\pi}{\exp{\!\left(\frac{2\pi j}{\lambda}\cdot re^{\theta j}\right)}\left(\frac{d\theta}{2\pi}\right)}&=\int_0^{2\pi}{\exp{\!\left(\frac{2\pi r}{\lambda}e^{\theta j}\cdot j\right)}\cdot\frac{2\pi r}{\lambda}e^{-\theta j}\,d\left(\frac{2\pi r}{\lambda}e^{\theta j}\right)\cdot\frac{1}{2\pi}} \\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\oint_C{e^{jz}\,\frac{dz}{z}} \\
&=1
\end{align*} by Cauchy's integral formula.

Thus the double integral is just $$\mathbb{E}\left[e^{\frac{2\pi jd_1}{\lambda}}\right]=\int_{R_{\text{min}}}^{R_{\text{max}}}{1\cdot f_d(r)\,dr}=1$$  The same argument shows $$\mathbb{E}\left[e^{-\frac{2\pi jd_2}{\lambda}}\right]=1$$

Substituting these values back in, $$\mathbb{E}\left[\left|\sum_i{\exp{\!\left(\frac{2\pi j}{\lambda}(d_i-d_k)\right)}}\right|^2\right]=N+2(N-1)\mathbb{E}\left[e^{\frac{2\pi jd_1}{\lambda}}\right]\mathbb{E}\left[e^{-\frac{2\pi jd_2}{\lambda}}\right]=3N-2$$

Worth noting: this solution implicitly assumes $\{d_i\}_i$ are chosen from 2D spheres (i.e., circles).  But the reason the contour integral comes out so nicely is just that $e^z$ is harmonic, so the average over a sphere is the same as the value at the center.  That is, we should expect the same result in higher dimensions.

Comment: why you have taken $d_1$ and $d_2$ only

Comment: @parveen: "The second [sum] has identically-distributed terms".  So it suffices to compute the expectation of one summand and multiply it by the number of terms.

Comment: okay you are right @jacob Manaker but my point is what should I take $d_1$ and $d_2$ interms of $d_i$ and $d_k$

Comment: @parveen: The end result (the expectation) is independent of which $d_i$ you choose for $d_k$ (!!!).  I didn't emphasize that in previous drafts of the answer, but I've stuck a sentence in on it.